# Cannot write csv file on ubuntu

Tags: python, csv, encoding, ubuntu-16.04, tweepy

iam running tweepy code on ubuntu server. my code running well on local machine and when i put it on ubuntu server the code does't work at all. i have try to create the output file it self but still the code won't run.

this is the code:

```
import tweepy
import time
import json
import csv
import sys
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener


consumer_key = '85gfoc9I'
consumer_secret = 'Cw'
access_token = '61'
access_secret = 'd4'

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

class Listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            jsonData = json.loads(data)
            createdAt = jsonData['created_at']
            userId = jsonData['id_str']
            userName = jsonData['user']['name']
            status = jsonData['user']['statuses_count']
            temen = jsonData['user']['friends_count']
            follower = jsonData['user']['followers_count']
            Namatempat = jsonData['place']['name']
            geo = jsonData['place']['bounding_box']['coordinates']
            text = jsonData['text']

            saveThis = createdAt +" :: "  + userId +" :: "  + userName+ " :: "  + str(status) + " :: "  + str(temen) + " :: "  + str(follower) + " :: "  + str(Namatempat) + " :: " +str(geo)+" :: " + text
            saveFile = open('tescsv.csv','a', encoding="utf-8")

            saveFile.write(saveThis)
            saveThis.encode('utf-8')
            saveFile.write('\n')

        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True
```

the error exception is :

```
Error on_data: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

what i have try :

1. i have been used saveFile = open('tescsv.csv', 'a') before and because they give me this = Error on_data: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f49b' in position 238: character maps to  error
2. i put = encoding="utf-8" the error is gone but when i put on my vps(ubuntu) they simply not working.
3. when i remove the encoding the server give me : Error on_data: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 222: o rdinal not in range(128) –

my guess is, there must be wrong with encoding and i need to install some thing  on the ubuntu server and that will be relate to csv. hope you can help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

`open` function does not have a keyword argument `encoding`, hence your error `'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`. Simple do:

`saveFile = open('tescsv.csv', 'a')`

Comment: thank you sir. i have been used saveFile = open('tescsv.csv', 'a') before and because they give me this = Error on_data: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f49b' in position 238: character maps to <undefined> error i put  = encoding="utf-8" the error is gone and when i put on my vps(ubuntu) they simply not working. and i remove the encoding the server give me : Error on_data: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 222: o           rdinal not in range(128)

Comment: while writing to the file you can use `saveFile.write(saveThis.encode("utf-8", "ignore"))`, you are using `.encode` after writing to file which will have no effect.

Comment: that give me this error : Error on_data: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: can u print `saveThis` for which the error is being raised?

Comment: the print result from saveThis is the twitter data that i need. and it print properly

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), it's `open (name[, mode[, buffering]])` where buffering is desired buffer size ranging from 0 (unbuffered), 1 (line buffered) to a positive integer for buffer size in bytes.

Your use of `encoding` in that `open()` is exactly as the error message says -- `an invalid keyword argument for this function`